# $window object not correctly injected

Tags: angularjs

I'm just wondering if anyone has experienced this issue and whether there is a fix for it. I'm injecting $window into my controller, but for some reason, `console.log($window)` is returning `function $get(name)`.

I am using `controllerAs` syntax, like so:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('subversionCmsApp')
        .controller('UserControlPanel', UserControlPanel);

  UserControlPanel.$inject = ['User', '$scope', '$state', '$q', '$timeout', '$filter', '$window', '$mdToast', '$mdDialog'];

  function UserControlPanel(User, $scope, $state, $q, $filter, $window, $mdToast, $mdDialog)
```

Unfortunately it seems that when I attempt to do `$window.innerWidth`, `undefined` is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm stupid. The order of parameters passed into the controller constructor must be the same as the order of parameters in the `$inject` array. Otherwise, angular will not correctly retrieve the service. Hope nobody else does this stupidity.